# Linux process stuck on wait for event even when event occurs

Tags: linux, kernel

I have a very strange system behavior in a few places which can be described in short: There is a process either in user or kernel space which waits for event, and although the event occurs, the process does not wakes up.

I will describe this below, but since the problem is in many different places (at least 4) I am starting to look for a system problem and not a local one something like preemption flag (already checked and not the problem) that will make the difference.

The system is Linux working on Freescale IMX6 which is brand new and still in beta phase. Same code is working well on many other Linux systems.

The system is running 2 separate processes, one is showing video using gstreamer playing from a file, using new image processor which has never been used. If this process runs alone the system can run over-night.

Another process is working with digital tuner connected over USB. The process only gets the device version in a loop, again when running alone can run over-night.

If these 2 process are running at the same time on the system, one is stuck within a few minutes. If we change the test parameters (like the periodic get version timing) the other process will get stuck.
The processes always stuck on wait for event (either `wait_event_interruptible` in kernel driver, or in user space on `pthread_cond_wait`). The event itself occurs and I have logs to see that. But the process does not wake up.

Trying to kill that process makes in Zombie. I managed to find one place with a very specific timing problem where condition check was misplaced and could cause this kind of stuck if the process was switched in the right place. It solved one problem and I got to another with the same characteristic. Anyway the bug that was found could not explain why it happens so often, it could explain theoretical bug which will stuck once in a lot of time, but not this fast.

Anyway - something in the system cause this to show up very fast even if the problem is real. Again - this code (except for the display driver which is new) is working in other systems, and even on the same system when working alone. Those processes are not related and not working with one another, the common about them is the machine they are running on.

It is probably has something to do with system resources (memory use 100M out of 1G, CPU usage is 5%), scheduler behavior or something on the system configuration. Anyone has ideas what could cause these kind of problems?

Comment: Did you use `strace` to understand what exact syscalls are done by the programs?

Comment: Enable debugging options in your `.config` and build kernel again.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a brand new port of Linux, then it may be that you actually have a real kernel bug - or a hardware bug if it's new hardware.

However, you need really good evidence, so `strace`, `ftrace` and perhaps even some instrumentation of the relevant kernel code to show this to someone who can actually fix the problem - I'm guessing that since you are asking this question in the way you are, that you are not a regular kernel hacker.

Sorry if this isn't really the answer you were looking for.